# Preprosser Directives not working correctly in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, preprocessor-directive

I had this code in Visual Studio 2015 and it worked fine. When I brought the project over to 2017 it stopped working. Basically it assumes DEBUG even when in release mode. In build properties the Define DEBUG constant is selected for DEBUG (as it should be) but is not selected for Release, yet when I change configurations, it still shows DEBUG. and everything after the else is grayed out.

```
#if DEBUG

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ODLConnection")));
#else
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ODLConnectionRealProduction")));
#endif
```

Comment: What is the version of your Visual Studio? Have you tried update it to the latest version? And I could not reproduce this it with a simple sample, if you can reproduce it with a simple sample, please share it to me, I will check if it still occur on my side.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8.7 which I believe is the latest. I have other project that I created in 2017 where this works. In the one project that was originally created in VS 2015, when I moved it over to 2017 it stopped working. It's the only project where it seems to not work. When I figure it out, I will update the post.

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: The solution seems to be upgrade to the latest Visual Studio. VS 2019 does not have this problem,

Answer (score 0):

I never did get this to work in Visual Studio 2017, but I recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2019 and like magic it started working again.. So basically the fix is: Upgrade to Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Solution Configuration manager has the project selected as the right configuration. I had a Project-Debug set to Debug. So my special DefineConstant was not being picked up.